# garage door opener replacement

Tags: garage, garage-door-opener, garage-door

i am looking to replace my current garage door opener. the images below show that the opener track was installed on an angled bracket along with the torsion spring. is it safe to remove the track screws on the angle bracket without having an issue with the spring losing its tension and causing injury?

[image: track header bracket]

[image: header bracket]

Comment: When I replaced my Craftsman with a Chamberlain, the new unit's bolt holes matched up perfectly with the old unit's holes.   I didn't have to muck with any of the other stuff.

Answer (score 2):

yeah it's safe if you are careful. The attachment points you can disconnect safely are circled in blue.

[image]

The torsion spring is attached to the bracket separately. Don't touch any of the other bolts on the bracket while the spring still has tension.